# Avoid Literals In If Condition

Tags: java, sonarqube, pmd

This part of code is rejected by pmd in sonar:

```
public String getFoo() {
    String foo = System.getProperty("foo");

    if (foo == null) {
        foo = System.getenv("foo");
    } else if (foo == null) {
        foo = "defaultFoo";
    }

    return foo;
}
```

It says "Avoid Literals In If Condition". Can someone tell me what's wrong with this or what this rule try to effect?

Comment: btw the second if is absolutely useless since you are trying to check something that was checked before

Comment: Avoid using hard coded literals in conditional statements, declare those as static variables or private members.

Comment: I edited the question and removed unsed part, bacause the answers are all focused to wrong part

Comment: Now also you are facing same reject ? If yes then create the static variable assigning null and then compare in if condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What does Sonar try to say is that you should avoid hardcoded literals (like `null`) in the `if` condition.

Suppose the following example:

Let's say we have this `if` statement, for which Sonar warns with *Avoid Literals In If Condition*:

```
if (i == 5) { 
    //do something
}
```

By declaring the hardcoded literal as (`final`) variable with descriptive names maintainability is enhanced:

```
final int FIVE = 5;
if (i == FIVE) {
    //do something
}
```

and Sonar doesn't warn anymore.

Comment: How to declarate null as final variable?

Comment: How about `final Object NULL = null;` ?

Comment: Yes, this is the reason. But in this case I think I'll remove this rule.

Comment: @kocko That seems like a mad thing to do, the same as  `final int FIVE = 5;`, it gains you nothing but "inner platform effect". Coding it as `final int TARGETVALUE= 5;` would be more useful though

Comment: This is the reason why some people hate static code analysis tools. I don't. But they do require configuration and customization in order to really help. Here, you could either limit yourself to magic numbers and use Checkstyle's MagicNumber check instead, or exclude `null` and other useful literals from this check.

Comment: @Thomas: If the value of a constant in an expression could not possibly change without rendering the code nonsensical, and it would be obvious from context why the constant is what it is, a literal is better than a named constant.  In many such cases, the real issue is a language deficiency (e.g. in the expression `if ((flags & FLIP_MODES) == 0)`, the literal zero isn't really a number; the purpose is to see if all the bits specified by `FLIP_MODES` are cleared, but there's no language feature to do that.

Comment: @supercat Well the language feature for flags is [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/EnumSet.html) which has an `isEmpty()` method to check if all flags are cleared. You are right of course for other cases; but you'd be surprised how few of those really exist.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you use:

```
public String getFoo() {
    String foo = System.getProperty("foo", "defaultFoo");

    return foo;
}
```

It will return `"defaultFoo"` if no property is found.

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: The question was focusing to reason why pmd rule dosen't compliant. But +1 becasue this is also good idea.